# Preview a "screen" in android jetpack compose navigation with a PreviewParameter NavController

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am discovering android Jetpack Compose (and Navigation) and try to display a preview of a view with a `navController` as parameter.

To achieve this, I use the `PreviewParameter` and I have no error, but nothing is displayed in the Preview window.

Does anyone know how pass a fake `NavController` instance to a Composable?

```
class FakeNavController : PreviewParameterProvider<NavController> {
    override val values: Sequence<NavController>
        get() {}
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview(
    @PreviewParameter(FakeNavController::class) fakeNavController: NavController
) {
    HomeView(fakeNavController)
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You don't have to make it nullable and pass null to it.
You just need to pass this: `rememberNavController()`

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    HomeView(rememberNavController())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution. Should be marked as one

Answer (score 6):

`PreviewParameter` is used to create multiple previews of the same view with different data. You're expected to return the needed values from `values`. In your example you return nothing that's why it doesn't work(it doesn't even build in my case).

That won't help you to mock the navigation controller, as you still need to create it somehow to return from `values`. I think it's impossible.

Instead you can pass a handler, in this case you don't need to mock it:

```
@Composable
fun HomeView(openOtherScreen: () -> Unit) {
    
}
// your Navigation view
composable(Destinations.Home) { from ->
    HomeView(
        openOtherScreen = {
            navController.navigate(Destinations.Other)
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem is to display a preview of a screen which take as parameter a NavController.
Because my screen is in another file, I don't know how to deal with it.
But your answer help me to understand the purpose of PreviewParameter. 
best regard

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I declare a nullable NavController and it works.

```
@Composable
fun HomeView(navController: NavController?) {
    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 4.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Home View",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Button(onClick = { navController?.navigate("lineRoute") }) {
                Text(text = "nav to Line view")
            }
        }
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview (){
    HomeView(null)
}
```

Comment: Hi, There's a way to inject mock nav controller to test the navigation in preview?

Comment: This doesn't work and doesn't even makes sense specially since we are suppose to use the preview parameter to display different states of the view